# Как циклом перебирать значения двух столбцов одновременно, чтобы они уовлетворяли условиям?

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, if

Как написать цикл, который будет перебирать значения двух столбцов DataFrame одновременно, чтобы они удовлетворяли условиям?

Например, вот мои два столбца:

```
Т   Д
10  0,2
10  0,3
20  0,29
45  0,45
69  0
6   -1
```

Мне нужно посчитать, в скольких сроках `Т<10`, но при этом `Д<0,2` (правильный ответ здесь, очевидно, 1: в последней строке).

Я могу посчитать количество удовлетворяющих меня повторений условия для каждого столбца отдельно:

```
arr = df['Т']
a = 0
for i in arr[:]:
    if i < 10:
        a += 1
```

Но вот как сделать комбинацию двух (а может и более) условий в разных `arr` пока не ясно.

Были попытки даже сделать так, но это бред полный, конечно:

```
a = 0
for i in df.columns:
    if i in df['Т'] < 10 and i in df['Д']<0.2:
        a += 1
```

Comment: что вы хотите получить в результате - число строк, удовлетворяющих условию или сами эти строки?

Comment: Только число строк. Хочу посчитать, склько раз такие комбинации встречаются

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [68]: res = len(df.query("Т < 10 and Д < 0.2"))

In [69]: res
Out[69]: 1
```

или так:

```
In [73]: ((df['Т'] < 10) & (df['Д'] < 0.2)).sum()
Out[73]: 1
```